# need to stop remove a tween animation

Tags: javascript, createjs

I've created some tweens but I need to stop them

As I need to reuse some assets with new tweens.
override:true helps for some, however,

This is the function, once it has been set off, with timers, they play regardless, as you can see there's alot of call backs

```
window.autoSurfaces = function(){
if(!window.gameStarted){ 
console.log("autoSurfaces");
playAutoScene();//start playing function to control numbers and alpha of wheels
var delay = 700
var animtime = 500

currentTween = createjs.Tween.get(leaves_anim).to({alpha:.7}, animtime).wait(800).call(leavesOut);//call end frame function
tweenAray.push(currentTween)
console.log(currentTween)
 leaves_anim.gotoAndPlay("go");

    function leavesOut(){
    currentTween = createjs.Tween.get(leaves_anim).to({alpha:0}, animtime).wait(200).call(snowIn);
    tweenAray.push(currentTween)
    console.log(currentTween)
     }

    function snowIn(){
    currentTween = createjs.Tween.get(snow_anim).to({alpha:1}, animtime).wait(800).call(snowOut)
    tweenAray.push(currentTween)
    console.log(currentTween)
    snow_anim.gotoAndPlay("go");
     }

     function snowOut(){
    currentTween = createjs.Tween.get(snow_anim).to({alpha:0}, animtime).wait(delay).call(stopAll);
    tweenAray.push(currentTween)
    //console.log("fired");

     function stopAll(){
     playAutoOut();
     leaves_anim.gotoAndStop(0);
     snow_anim.gotoAndStop(0);

        }
     }
 }
```

}

I set a global var of currentTween then:

```
currentTween = createjs.Tween.get(target).to({alpha:.7}, animtime).wait(800).call(callHandler);
```

then:

```
removeTweens(currentTween);
```

tried setting an array - tweenAray.push(currentTween)

```
tweenAray.removeTweens(currentTween)
```

Also
    createjs.Tween.removeAllTweens();

Even

```
createjs.Tween.removeAllTweens = function() {
var tweens = createjs.Tween._tweens;
for (var i=tweens.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    tweens[i]._paused = true;
    tweens.splice(i,1);
}
```

};

Nothing happens or I get errors
I'm exporting from Flash CS6

Any pointers?

Cheers

Comment: does anyone have any idea?
was thinking about maybe using a timeline tween, would I be able to stop all timers etc within that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but here's a quick stab at it...

Using override will cause a new tween to stop any previous tweens with the same target. Ex.

`createjs.Tween.get(foo).to({x:100, alpha:0.5}, 200);
createjs.Tween.get(foo, {override:true}).to({x:500}, 500);`

The second tween will override the first tween, because they both target `foo`. The first tween will not run.

If you want to stop tweens, just hold onto references to the tweens, and use `setPaused(true)`. That effectively kills the tween.

`var tweensToKill = [];
tweensToKill.push( new createjs.Tween.get(foo).etc(...) );
tweensToKill.push( new createjs.Tween.get(bar).etc(...) );
// ... later:
while (tweensToKill.length) {
    tweensToKill.pop().setPaused(true);
}`

Comment: Thanks for that

The while loop was the best way to go, do you know of any tutorials or examples of chaining and timeline tweens, haven't been able to find any, but it might be the best option for the future

Thanks again